# What did the girls from Usagi Team watch on Final Eve?

Tags: girls-und-panzer

At the night before Final Battle against Kuromorimine Girls High School on episode 10, all girls from Usagi Team are seen watching a movie, and it looks like a movie about tank.

[image]

What movie was it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They were watching [Kelly's Heroes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly's_Heroes)  It's an old war movie in 1970 about a group of American soldier who tried to rob a bank far behind enemy line.

[image: A DVD poster from anime]

While the original poster looks different, it match with Japanese poster for the movie

[image: Kelly's Heroes official poster]
[image: Japanese version of Kelly's Heroes official poster]

The scene they were watching is around 1:56:00 when Oddball and Kelly, the main character, shoot down a Tiger, the same tank with Kuromorimine's tank.

[image: Oddball and Kelly shoot down a Tiger in anime][image: Oddball and Kelly shoot down a Tiger in movie]

---

**Notes:**

- The girls seems to use the same tactic against Elefant, they manages to outmaneuver Elefant, and shoot it down from behind in a narrow road. Initially, they shouted, "Operation: Kelly's Heroes".
- When Yukari infiltrated Saunders, she called herself "Sgt. Oddball, third class" from the "6th Armored Division." Which I believe came from Oddball from Kelly's Heroes